# Multiple check box clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Table Tag

```
<tr>
   <td>
     <input id="chkbox" name="chkbox" type="checkbox" class="Checkbox" value = <%: item.field1 %> />
   </td>
   <td>
      <%: item.field1 %>
   </td>
   <td>
      <%: item.field2 %>
   </td>
   </tr>
```

My Jquery

```
        $("#Free").click(function fn() {
            if ($('#chkbox').is(':checked')) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert("Please Select option");
                return false;
            }
        });
```

my check box are clicked but it always showing else part that alert message "Please Select Option"

Comment: do you have multiple checkboxes in the page with the id `chkbox`

Comment: yes but i select checkboxes it shown only alert message

Comment: that is could be the problem id of an element must be unique

Comment: Yes its should be unique only but now it validate only first the check box but its doesn't validate any other check box

Comment: that is how the id selector works... it fetches the first element with the given id

Comment: Then how i can solve it. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have multiple input fields in your DOM with `id="chkbox"`. This results in invalid markup and your `$('#chkbox')` selector is always returning the first element.

You could use the class name instead:

```
<input name="chkbox" type="checkbox" class="Checkbox" value = <%: item.field1 %> />
```

and then:

```
$("#Free").click(function() {
    if ($('.Checkbox:checked').length > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("Please Select option");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Also from your question it is not quite clear what this `#Free` is, whether it is a single button or you have such buttons on each table row.

If it is a single button then the previous code should be alright -> it ensures that there is at least one checkbox that is checked.

If you have many such buttons then you should use a class selector for them (after assigning each button the same `class`) and then:

```
$(".Free").click(function() {
    var checkbox = $(this).closest('tr').find('.Checkbox');
    if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("Please Select option");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Also notice that you had some invalid javascript in the .click event:

```
.click(function fn() {
```

which I fixed to using an anonymous function:

```
.click(function() {
```